# Echo javascript variable into smarty

Tags: javascript, smarty

I set one variable in java-script. And I want to echo that variable in smarty.

Would it be possible?

If yes then please provide me some guidance.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking (i.e. unless you are doing something esoteric such as mixing SSJS and PHP) you can't.

The PHP runs (processing the Smarty template), then delivers the output to the browser, and *then* the JavaScript runs, but which time it is too late to get any data back.

You could use JavaScript to work out what data you want, and then make a new request to the server. e.g. by setting `location` to a new URI or by using XMLHttpRequest to get new data from the server and then use that to modify the document with JS. However, since you are looking at the Smarty level, it is likely that you only want to the data for formatting, in which case you should just do it in JS (with DOM manipulation).

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request to send it to the server, where you can use Smarty to render new HTML (don't know the details of this), then return HTML in the AJAX response.  You can then inject this with `innerHTML` or similar.

You can look at the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest) object.  However, various JavaScript frameworks can greatly simplify this.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I am trying to achieve this with an AJAX.