# Assign JavaScript variable to Smarty variable

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to assign a javascript variable to a smarty variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271026/how-to-assign-a-javascript-variable-to-a-smarty-variable)

I want to assign a textfield value to Smarty variable using JavaScript and call Smarty function but I could not do it.

Please guide me.

Comment: Javascript is executed on client side, Smarty - on server side. There is no way for javascript to contact with php (smarty) directly in the current request. Other method - AJAX.

Comment: Smarty is PHP and runs on the **server side**. JavaScript runs on the **client side**. When the JavaScript is executed, PHP's job is already done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to assign a javascript variable to a smarty variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271026/how-to-assign-a-javascript-variable-to-a-smarty-variable) and [Echo javascript variable into smarty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633172/echo-javascript-variable-into-smarty) and [Variable from Javascript -> Php -> Smarty… is it possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672929/variable-from-javascript-php-smarty-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that in an easy way. PHP, and by extension Smarty, is parsed and run on the server side before the browser get the data. JavaScript is run on the client side when the browser parses the HTML, CSS and Javascript that the server sent.

You will have to make a new HTTP request in some way, sending the new data. You can do that by reloading the entire web page and sending stuff in the querystring (after `?` in the URL), or slightly more advanced by doing an Ajax call from your JS code and make JS do the changes of the page that you desire. The latter is more complex and requires some knowledge of Javascript, but the page does not need to be reloaded in its entirety.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean something like this?

```
<script>
var foo_bar = {$foo.bar|escape:javascript};
</script>
```

Note that, as mentioned above, the value is computed server-side.

**UPD.** I get it now, you wanted to pass value the other way around. No, that’s not possible.